# Mongoose: convert _id types in existing collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, uuid, mongoose-schema

I have an existing mongoose collection with using the default ObjectID type for _id.

I want to migrate this collection to use a UUID for the _id, ideally without a special migration step.

My new schema makes use of the package `mongoose-uuid4`:

```
var uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
require('mongoose-uuid4')(mongoose);

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { type: mongoose.Types.UUID, default: uuidv4 },
    ...
});

const Model = mongoose.model('Model', schema);
```

My theory here is that my existing ObjectIDs could be zero-padded to be valid UUID objects, so I should be able to write my access methods so I can find by either a short ObjectID or a full UUID.

If I do a Model.find({}) on this collection, the documents come back with no _id fields, but I do get an exception thrown that says it couldn't cast the id value to a UUID:

```
ValidationError: <Model> validation failed: undefined: Could not cast 6132ba2d6474631eeb038a9b to UUID.
```

So this makes me think there's a place where I can insert some code to do a type conversion to make this work, because some part of the mongoose stack tried to do this conversion, but didn't know how to.

My first preference is an on-the-fly way of allowing existing _id fields to get upgraded, but I am also ok with a one-time 'fixup' pass through the collection to upgrade fields.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The `_id` field in the MongoDB document is immutable - it cannot be changed.

Comment: I'm not looking for a way to change individual document; just a way for old and new types of _ids to coexist.